# Leaflet lng/lat relative to image

Tags: javascript, leaflet, chromium-embedded

In my application I'm using CEF (chromium embedded framework) to render a webpage into my program. So for my worldmap I found leaflet to be pretty awesome. While the mapgeneration works perfect I now try to convert the lat/lng values to the coordinates of my game. So basically an image is 256x256 pixels and on zoom level 7 one 256x256 tile consist of 64x64 blocks (4x4 chunks by 16x16 blocks). Each block is 1 unit. By empiric tests I've found that 1 lng/lat is approximately 24 blocks, but not exactly. For my application I need the precise values.

So my question is: Is there a way to convert the coordinates from leaflet to the coordinates in my application? To recapitulate:
On zoom level 7 one 256x256 tile is 64x64 units wide (in game coordinates)

Many thanks in advance

Cromon

Answer (score 1):

Use [latLngToContainerPoint](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-latlngtocontainerpoint) on your `map` object in order to compute the offset from top-left of the map element.